# Trying to transfer domain out of Area 53 in AWS: Namecheap stuck at 'Awaiting release from previous registrar'

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, domain, domain-registrar, namecheap

The domains are .com and .org respectively and I have unlocked them both in AWS.

I have already used Area 53 to begin the transfer, but like the title says: Namecheap is still waiting, after about 24 hours, for AWS, with the message 'Awaiting release from previous registrar.'

What do I do? I already payed namecheap for the transfer and I'm doing the transfer specifically because I'm having so many issues with amazon.

Please Help! I Can provideenter image description here more details if necessary.

[Namecheap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS0DY.png)
[Domain 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smusc.png)
[Domain 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOoJ3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Namecheap correctly informed me on twitter that I'm proceeding correctly and that I should wait.

They were right; Apparently I didn't see the verification emails from AWS. Once I clicked on the notifications and selected 'yes' everything sorted it self out fairly quickly.